# What is this called in Mathematics

Tags: problem-solving, programming

I am not a Mathematician.  I am a programmer.  While working on a mock interview question I noticed something I found interesting.

The problem was to return the *smallest* number (N), whose sum of its digits totaled another supplied/known number (X).(There was other stuff leading up to that too)

- given 12, the answer is 39
- given 62, the answer is 8999999
- given 156, the answer is 399999999999999999

I realised dividing any number (X) by 9, and placing the first digit after the decimal at the start, followed by Y number of 9's (Where Y is how many times 9 goes into the X), would give the smallest answer as required.

44/9=4.8888
return 89999

My colleagues just did a while loop until the got a number. Which I think is yucky.

I know I'm not some math genius.  Can someone tell me what this is called?  I have no idea.  Is it just basic division :)

Comment: Yes, it is just basic division, but it is a cool find!

Comment: I totally agree, going on a loop is horribly yucky... think of the runtime of the naive algorithm trying to find the number for an input like $10000$... (*/shudder...*)

Comment: Integer division effectively. Note that $44 = 4 * 9 + 8$. The quotient $4$ is the number of $9$, and the remainder $8$ is the first digit of the result (if different of $0$)

Comment: I think it is easy to show that the minimum number must contain only nines , apart from the first digit (unless the desired sum is divisible by $9$). This number is easy to find : $\lfloor \frac{n}{9} \rfloor$ nines and if we are still below the given sum, we add the first digit to get the desired sum.

Comment: I do not think there is a name, but inspired by a similar naming from Vepir , I suggest "minimal-summer" (which is here not meant as the hot season!)

Comment: Thank you for the positive comments and thoughts. Minimal-summer it is ☺️